# Why does the `instanceof` operator return false on instance passed to library? (No inheritance involved)

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, class, instanceof

I am building a library with TS. This library uses the `ssh2` library as a dependency.

I'm trying to create a function that can either accept an `ssh2` configuration object or an already existing `Client` instance to execute a command (this is a simplified case):

```
import { Client, ConnectConfig } from 'ssh2';

export function runCommand(params: Client | ConnectConfig) {
  if(params instanceof Client) {
    // do something
  } else {
    // create our own client
    // do something
  }
}
```

When I build this library and call the function like so:

```js
const { readFileSync } = require("fs");
const { Client } = require("ssh2");
const { runCommand } = require("myLib");
const conn = new Client();

conn
  .on("ready", () => {
    console.log("Client :: ready");
    runCommand(conn);
  })
  .connect({
    host: "example.com",
    port: 22,
    username: "me",
    privateKey: readFileSync(process.env.HOME + "/.ssh/id_ed25519"),
  });
```

the `instanceof` check in my function will return `false` for some reason. What exactly is happening here? Is it a TS compilation issue or does Node.js see the `Client` from my lib's dependency and my consumer code's dependency as two different classes?

The compiled code looks something like:

```js
const ssh2_1 = require("ssh2");
//...
function runCommand(params) {
    if (params instanceof ssh2_1.Client) {
        // do something
    }
    else {
       // create our own client
    // do something
    }
}
```

Comment: *'runCommand(conn); // this is where it fails'* What error are you getting? Have you debugged or logged the `instanceof` value in that function? Have you inspected the compiled code?

Comment: I'm not getting any errors. It's just that `params instanceof Client` within `runCommand` returns `false`. I will add the compiled code to the question.

Comment: "_as two different classes_" most probably indeed; how do build your library? Is `ssh2` bundled?

Comment: @ghybs Yes, `ssh2` is bundled. As in, it's added as a dependency in the lib's `package.json`. I am building it with `"target": "ES6"` and `"target": "ES2022"` (two separate builds to support CommonJS and ES import/export)

Comment: Probably two different objects called `Client`. Many libraries ship with multiple modules to import from - AMD, CJS, and ES6 for whatever flavour of the module system you use. I suspect that's the case here and in which case you'd be importing two different `Client` objects that still do the same thing.

Comment: You might have a different resolution for ssh2, which gives you a different instance of Client (so the instanceof fails).  Check that your library and app code are using the same dependency, and check your module resolution setup to ensure they are looking in the same place (require/import might have different resolution depending on build tools).

Comment: Thank you, @VLAZ and @Dave. But since the library cannot dictate which exact `Client` class the dev is using, what would be a better way to check whether `params` is an instance of `Client`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What may not be obvious from the behaviour of `instanceof` operator, is that the class must be *exactly* in the parent chain, in the sense of JavaScript object *reference*.

Hence, if you import `Client` class twice, they are different actual object references, and `instanceof` may give a "false" negative.

This is very probably what happens here: `ssh2` is bundled with your library, hence it imports its own copy of the dependency. Whereas your app imports `ssh2` on its own, leading to a *separate* copy.

You have a few options:

- Do not bundle the dependency with your library (e.g. with webpack `externals`), let the app install a *single* version that both your library and app will import; typical case of specifying `peerDependencies`
- Do not use the `instanceof` operator; instead, use some heuristic to determine whether the object has the shape you need; typically check for some properties and their type
- Re-export the dependency (e.g. `Client` class in your case) from your library, and use that one in your app (`const { Client, runCommand } = require("myLib");`), so that it is the exact same copy (since it is already bundled, why not re-using it instead of re-bundling it?)

Comment: I think you're right. This is actually a bit of a bummer. unfortunately I cannot just expose my own `Client` because the lib is going to be used in a plugin for an environment where an ssh2 `Client` and I need to have it as a dependency, because that same environment allows opening up more connections.

Comment: I think I will go with your second suggestion. `instanceof EventEmitter` seems to work consistently during runtime. I guess I will check against that, since `Client` extends `EventEmitter` along with some additional checks to see if required methods exist on the instance.

Comment: @ghybs What would you say about such a comparison? I can see that it returns `true`, but not sure how reliable it is in cases like described in a question. `obj.constructor instanceof MyClass.constructor`

Comment: @szelbi: This sounds like a very similar situation, hence with the exact same limitation. But feel free to open a new question with exact details of your specific situation.